# Process the flag value set under getJson under for loop which iterates over every URL

Tags: javascript, getjson

I am working on a report which generates Diff report URLs everyday(since 2016)
I parse those reports(in JSON) to find some string which indicates regression and mark a flag (regressionFound = true) in the JS. I am then using this flag in the HTML code to show the text as "Regression Found" for the regression that day

The problem is for all the reports whether or not it shows regression shows as regressionFound = false. I assume this is because of getJSON being asynchronous. Any work around this?

```
    for (var j=0; j<reports.length; j++) {
       // some code
      var ReportPath = buildURL(j);
      regressionFound = false
      (function(url) {
          $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            if (some condition //regression found) {
                regressionFound = true;
            }      
         });
      })(ReportPath);
    }
```

Comment: Do you not need a `regressionFound` for each report? Where do you actually manipulate the html?

Comment: Yes I do need regressionFound for each report? I manipulate in .html file.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating array of the request promises and use `$.when()` or `Promise.all()` to run code after all the requests complete. With each request you could add a `regressionFound` property to each report object

```
var requests = reports.map(function(report, i){
   return $.getJSON(buildURL(i)).then(function (data){
       report.regressionFound = // conditional
   });    
});

$.when.apply(null, requests).then(function(){
   // all requests completed and report objects are updated
   // loop over reports and modify html
})
```